# JavaFX Area Charts and adding dynamic labels following cursor

Tags: layout, charts, javafx

I'd like to to be able to add a label to a chart that follows the cursor. I've already seen several examples of this on stack overflow already that attach labels to the values/nodes of a series but I want to be able to do this for the whole of the area chart. My problem comes when I want to add a label (ultimately a floating box of values). I'm struggling to figure out how I can do this and maintain the layout of the scene. When I add the chart to the scene as the dedicated item the chart renders as expected. But when I add a label to the scene it is shared and the chart no longer fills the entire canvas

```
Group root = new Group();
root.getChildren().addAll(sac,myLabel);
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600); // Now the Chart shares the scene with the label
```

I want to add the label so I can use it as the mouse moves over a chart and then simply translate it to the cursor position. I've no problem with the mouse events just that I can't seem to share a scene with objects that are transient. I believe this is down to a lack of understanding on how to manage this particular situation. It's entirely likely the solution to this problem is to dynamically generate this label and not have it as a static scene object. Any help gratefully received.

Full test case below (Java 8)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.StackedAreaChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class AreaChartTestCase extends Application {

    final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis(1, 31, 1);
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final StackedAreaChart<Number, Number> sac
            = new StackedAreaChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);
    Label myLabel = new Label();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("Area Chart Sample");
        sac.setTitle("Temperature Monitoring (in Degrees C)");
        XYChart.Series<Number, Number> seriesApril
                = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        seriesApril.setName("April");
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 4));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 10));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 15));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 8));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 5));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(15, 18));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(18, 15));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(21, 13));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(24, 19));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(27, 21));
        seriesApril.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(30, 21));
        XYChart.Series<Number, Number> seriesMay
                = new XYChart.Series<Number, Number>();
        seriesMay.setName("May");
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, 20));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(3, 15));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(6, 13));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(9, 12));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(12, 14));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(15, 18));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(18, 25));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(21, 25));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(24, 23));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(27, 26));
        seriesMay.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(31, 26));

        final Node chartPlotBackground = sac.lookup(".chart-plot-background");
        chartPlotBackground.setOnMouseEntered((MouseEvent mouseEvent) -> {
            myLabel.setVisible(true);
        });

        chartPlotBackground.setOnMouseExited((MouseEvent mouseEvent) -> {
            myLabel.setVisible(false);
        });

        chartPlotBackground.setOnMouseMoved((MouseEvent mouseEvent) -> {
            myLabel.setText("Location : X = " + mouseEvent.getSceneX() + " : Y = "+ mouseEvent.getSceneY());
            myLabel.setTranslateX(mouseEvent.getSceneX());
            myLabel.setTranslateY(mouseEvent.getSceneY());
        });

        Group root = new Group();
        root.getChildren().addAll(sac, myLabel);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600); // Now the Chart shares the scene with the label
        sac.getData().addAll(seriesApril, seriesMay);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the sample, your label depends on the `mouseEvent.getSceneX/Y` values, which doesn't seem particularly useful.   Is this what you actually want? Or do you want the label to depend on some chart specific value? If so, it is related to the area the mouse is hovering over or the exact point the mouse is at?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. To be honest the tracking of the mouse is just to demonstrate what I'm attempting to do. I'm fairly certain I can make that much elegant. The real issue is that I don't understand how to add the label to the scene and then apply a layout so the chart maximises in the window/canvas and the label isn't bound a specific layout region. Basically my issue is more fundamental than that... A group enables me to do this but it doesn't appear that I can then maximise the chart.

Answer (score 1):

So I think I've solved it. At least to a level that meets my requirements.

```
    Group root = new Group();
    root.setManaged(false);
    root.getChildren().add(ac);
    root.getChildren().add(myLabel);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    scene.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldSceneWidth, Number newSceneWidth) {
            ac.setPrefWidth((double) newSceneWidth);
        }
    });
    scene.heightProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldSceneHeight, Number newSceneHeight) {
            ac.setPrefHeight((double) newSceneHeight);
        }
    });
```

By listening to changes in the width and height properties and manually managing the layout of the chart and label I was able to get the layout and functionality I required.I'm not 100% sure if this the optimal approach but it works.